# AJAX request - can't get div content

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is part of my AJAX request.
It works fine - sending `code` to `index.php`
But when I would like get some content `(div id="editor")` from response I'm getting only something like that `[object Object]`

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'index.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
         content: code
      },
      success: function(data){
          alert($('#editor'));
      }
```

When I change function to:

```
success: function(data){
          alert(data);
     }
```

I am getting whole source code of page

Comment: I am assuming the data has the element with id editor if so try $('#editor',$(data))

Comment: on your external page, is your #editor ID a child of another ID?

Comment: can you print on here what the data shows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the scope of where jQuery is searching. (which is the second parameter of a jQuery selector and by default 'document').

```
alert($('#editor',data));
```

Also, you are currently getting [object Object] because alert cannot split out the object as a sting without a little help. try `console.log($('#editor',data))` or `alert($('#editor',data).html())`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to get out of div, try

```
alert($('#editor').text());
```

or

```
alert($('#editor').html());
```

Comment: as locrizak pointed out, you may need to change the scope as well